# Google Forms / Excel / Gmail Integration - Linking the Excel Sheet to the Google Docs template which will be used in the e-mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

I am a legal ops specialist working in a law firm with an interest of coding but have no practice lately. (I had python course during my studies but that was years ago)

Therefore I may be asking a very easy question, because I used an existing template and modified it for our process, however because of my lack of information on the topic I can't find the cause of the problem we are having.

So [this](https://techandeco.medium.com/workflow-to-collect-and-approve-budgets-using-apps-script-in-google-sheets-f713adba5d11) is the template I used and the guide about it.
The problem is, when i filled the form any send a mail to the approvals it doesn't fill the answer template(docs) so the e-mail I receive comes as following;
[table in the email template which is supposed to be fed from the google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGRDo.png)

Which is basically the names of the google sheets columns, not the value in the cell. I believe the problem might be about the following piece of code;

```
// We start with the doc template HTML body, and then we replace
        // each '{{fieldName}}' with the row's respective value.
        let emailBody = headers.reduce(
          (result, fieldName) => result.replace(`{{${fieldName}}}`, row[fieldName]),
          docToHtml(templates.get(emailTemplate || action))
        );
```

OR, because I couldn't manage to link the table in the google docs template with the answer sheet and I don't know how to do it.

Any kind of help is appreciated, I'm very cold and lost out here.

Edit1: Screenshots of the answer sheet and related part of the code.
[answer sheet - columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1mcX.png)[const part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adcfh.png)

Edit2: I added a screenshot of the template provided by Google. You can see that there is a link between the template and the answer sheet. I couldn't manage to restore such link when I changed the google docs template. [Google docs template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v24a.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from the script of `I believe the problem might be about the following piece of code;`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect in your showing script? And also, I cannot understand `because I couldn't manage to link the table in the google docs template with the answer sheet and I don't know how to do it.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Are you trying to get the data from response fields of google form and use it to replace in the google doc template or you're trying to send email later in one go?  How the following line of code is executing?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comments and your help in advance. The process that I would like to follow is explained here(https://techandeco.medium.com/workflow-to-collect-and-approve-budgets-using-apps-script-in-google-sheets-f713adba5d11) I changed some parts of the code and added different columns(google form questions) Therefore I lost the link between google template and the answer sheet.

Comment: Process goes as; user fills the google form, authorized user(manager) checks the information given from the google answer sheet and decides what to do (approve, decline etc.), chooses the action and then clicks "Send e-mail" button to the approved lines. In this e-mail there is a google doc template which has a table. This table needs to be filled with the approved line of the answer sheet.

Comment: The idea is basically asking for budget approval via google forms, manager sees the budget details from google sheet and sends an approval email to the finance department by using the "send e-mail" button on the answer sheet. And finance department sees what budget their manager approved and the details of the budget.

Comment: Code is not really very clear and doctohtml is not defined.  So it's rather difficult to provide any assistance.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand your current issue of your showing script. And also, I couldn't understand the sample input and output values you expect in your showing script. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: in the original files, the {{SHORTCODE}} must be same spelling as the column header that it matches with toUpperCase. So to troubleshoot further you will need to provide screenshots of the Form Responses header row and the section of the Apps Script where it lists the CONST (rows 1 to 20 of the Apps Script).

Comment: @Cooper the docToHtml is a custom function at line 172 of the Apps Script. the original Spreadsheet/Form/Docs combo works without modifications. However the OP has added more columns, removed parts of the Apps Script, and Changed all the data in the docs. So we need to see if the changes were also made in the Form Responses header row and that everything matches accordingly.

Comment: Hello! I added two screenshots, hope it helps you to understand what is wrong with my modifications. :(

Comment: In addition to the screenshots you asked for, I also added the screenshot of google docs template which shows a link that I couldn't manage to rebuilt. @MrShane

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: regarding Edit 2, that is just a linked spreadsheet, that is used to create the table in the docs. this is not the cause of the problems. the cause is related to the many changes made from the original apps script and short codes.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, as strange as it sounds, i have discovered that the main issue is the font type.

Also, it appears not possible to use a placeholder more than 1 time on the same email.

The evidence i have is that, by using a text editor to create the placeholder, i set ALL of the values in the doc row to {{Name}}, and in the Form Responses i set the name value to 1000.

The first 1 worked, then i typed over the second value with a different placeholder, and it began to work too.

So, you should recreate all the placeholders in a text editor, then copy and paste them onto the doc.
[image]